# Alternatives to develop relationships without dialogue

Tags: character-development, plot, dialogue, relationships

I have to come up with an idea (this is an assignment) for a story between 1 or 2 characters without dialogue and with a length of 90 seconds, so I know it's totally possible, however, when it comes to develop drama in a friendship relationship between those characters it becames very hard to do it without dialogue, how do you depict relationship development without any spoken dialogue?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, could you edit it to ask more specifically what you want to know?

Comment: What do you mean, you "have to come up with an idea"? Is this for a student assignment? If so, is developing a relationship part of the assignment, or is that something you want to do? Also, define "relationship". Do you specifically mean a romantic relationship? (Or would boss and employee, parent and child, friends, neighbours, strangers stuck in an elevator, etc. also count?)

Comment: Yes, thank you for the feedback, let me just edit the question